# Google Enhanced Ecommerce, set_checkout_option

Tags: google-analytics, enhanced-ecommerce

I integrated Google Enhanced Ecommerce on a project and integrated calls for the various checkout steps (billing address, shipping address, shipping method and payment method). I'm correctly sending the 'set_checkout_option' event and I set the steps for GA administration, but I still see the steps not populated. Has anyone been in the same situation?

PS: Billing address I think it is always populated because of course it is step 1 and it takes it automatically with the 'begin_checkout' event.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please share the relevant part of your code?

Comment: ex: gtag('event', 'set_checkout_option', {
      "checkout_step": 2,
      "checkout_option": "payment_method"
      "value": "paypal"
    });

Comment: Are you using the checkout_progress call as well? I think the set_checkout_option can be used to decorate already tracked steps.

Comment: Yes, checkout_progress is called immediately after set_checkout_option.

gtag('event', 'checkout_progress', {
      "items": {..},
      "coupon": ""
    });

Answer (score 4):

You have to add the **checkout_step** parameter when calling the **checkout_progress** event.

```
gtag('event', 'checkout_progress', {
    "checkout_step": 2,
    "items": [...]

});
gtag('event', 'set_checkout_option', {
    "checkout_step": 2,
    "checkout_option": "payment_method",
    "value": "paypal"
});
```

Comment: I've never seen him in any tutorial. Do you have a link?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/gtagjs/reference/event -> see the list of parameters for checkout_progress, it lists checkout_step as one of them.  Making this change worked for me.